# Issue with reading data with apache POI. Data is read but excel file is corrupted afterwards

Tags: java, apache-poi

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelData {
    File fs;
    FileInputStream fis;
    XSSFWorkbook workbook;
    XSSFSheet sheet;
    FileOutputStream fos;

    public ExcelData(String datafile_path) throws Exception{

        fs=new File(datafile_path);
        fis=new FileInputStream(fs);
        workbook=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        fos=new FileOutputStream(fs);

public Object readData(int sheet_num, int row_num, int column_num) throws Exception{

        sheet=workbook.getSheetAt(sheet_num);
        //sheet.getRow(row_num).getCell(column_num).CELL_TYPE_STRING;
        Object data = null;
        if (sheet.getRow(row_num).getCell(column_num).getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING){
            data=sheet.getRow(row_num).getCell(column_num).getStringCellValue();
        } else if (sheet.getRow(row_num).getCell(column_num).getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC){
            data=sheet.getRow(row_num).getCell(column_num).getNumericCellValue();
        }
        workbook.close();
        //String data=sheet.getRow(row_num).getCell(column_num).getStringCellValue();
workbook.close();
        fis.close();        
return data;

    }
```

----This code is working in reading the data. All the data is read successfully but after execution when look at the file, it is corrupted and size is 0 kb from 10 kb.

Comment: this is java , not javascript. They are as closely related as ham and hamburger

Comment: Why you are opening `FileOutputStream` for the file? `Workbook.close` will close that output stream but nothing is written to it. So the file is empty then. You should not open an output stream if you do'nt want to write something to it.

Answer (score 0):

Following snippet works for ".xls" file extension

```
public String[][] readFile(String filePath) throws IOException, BiffException {
    int totalNoOfRows, totalNoOfCols;

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);

    Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fis);

    // To get the access to the sheet
    Sheet sh = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");

    // To get the number of rows present in sheet
    totalNoOfRows = sh.getRows();
    // To get the number of columns present in sheet
    totalNoOfCols = sh.getColumns();

    String[][] excelData = new String[totalNoOfRows][totalNoOfCols];

    for (int row = 0; row < totalNoOfRows; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < totalNoOfCols; col++) {
            excelData[row][col] = sh.getCell(col, row).getContents();
        }
    }

    wb.close();
    fis.close();
    return excelData;
}
```

Comment: `Workbook.getWorkbook` is **not** `apache poi`. It is `jxl`. So this code is not relevant for this question.